# Connecting from WCF Web Service to MS SQL Database via ODBC Security

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, security, odbc

I have a WCF Web Service which is contacted via an iPhone App over HTTPS Protocol. This Web Service then connects to another database via ODBC SQL Connection. Is the connection between my Web Service and the Database via ODBC secure? If not, how can I make sure, that there won't be any security issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad topic so I suggest you start here: [Securing SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283235.aspx)

Start with making sure the database is behind a firewall so it's not directly accessible over the internet.

Fortunately, the use of WCF services does not complicate the topic. You can still follow the general best practices.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a look into it.